# how to send value var s from jquery to show in input tag id="text_var"?

Tags: php, jquery

How to send value var s from jquery to show in input tag id="text_var" ?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="text_var">
<input name="offer_image_1" type="file" id="offer_image_1" onchange("loadname(this,'previewimg')") size="50" />   

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#offer_image_1').bind('change', function() {  // for check size image
          var s = this.files[0].name;
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are trying to set the value of `#text-var` to `s`. Since you are using jQuery 1.8.3 (> 1.7), use of `on()` is preferred over `bind()`:

```
$('#offer_image_1').on('change', function() {
    var s = this.files[0].name;
    $('#text_var').val(s);
});
```

If, as mentioned in the comments, you are placing the value in a `div`, then you would use `html()` instead:

```
$('#text_var').html(s);
```

Comment: if i want to show var s in <div id="text_var"></div> , how can i do ?

Comment: You would do `$('#text_var').html(s)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this also, it will show input file value in text_var input

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#offer_image_1").change(function () {
        var s = this.files[0].name;
        $('#text_var').val(s); 
    });
  });
```